# Is it possible to increase the attention scores for a part of a sequence for Transformer models?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, attention-model

Say I have a sequence of tokens:

```
my_seq = "Chocolate has a history of human consumption tracing back to 400 AD and is rich in polyphenols such as catechins, anthocyanidins, and pro anthocyanidins. As chocolate and cocoa product consumption, along with interest in them as functional foods, increases worldwide, there is a need to systematically and critically appraise the available clinical evidence on their health effects."
```

Is it possible to increase/decrease the attention scores such that my model will put more/less emphasis on the first 10 tokens in that sequence?

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel, AutoConfig
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    "gpt2",
    vocab_size=len(tokenizer),
    n_ctx=1024,  # Define your desired context length
    bos_token_id=tokenizer.bos_token_id,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
)

gpt2_model = GPT2LMHeadModel(config).to(device)
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(my_seq, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
```

I found that models can often take a tensor of `attention_mask`:

```
output = gpt2_model.generate(
    input_ids=input_ids,
    attention_mask=attention_mask,
    max_length=50,  # Adjust as needed
    num_return_sequences=1,  # Number of output sequences you want
)
```

But from [here](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/clarification-on-the-attention-mask/1538) I understand that it's just a binary tensor.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: From a technical perspective, you can do that, but from a performance perspective, it is (probably) not a good idea. You also need to keep in mind that if you train the model, it will probably compensate for it over time. What are you planning to do? For me, it seems like your sequence consists of different types of tokens and you want the model to treat them differently. Have you tried introducing a special token for it? You could also try to add another embedding layer for the types.

Comment: @cronoik How would you do it from a technical perspective? And you're right, the sequence consists of different types of tokens and we want the model to treat them differently. We have other approaches as well, like special tokens, prompts, etc. But we also wanted to try an attention based approach

Comment: [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.15910.pdf) modified the attention weights somehow with some scalar, but I'm not entirely sure how / if that's what you had in mind

Comment: The paper you mentioned seems to modify the weights of attention heads (compare section 6), while your question refers to scores. Could you please confirm what you want to know?

Comment: @cronoik Apologies, scores/weights/values seem synonyms to me. The goal is to keep the architecture the same but modify something in the attention calculations. Is the clearer?